Number not formatting correctly for locale countries when the range in between 1000 - 9999 in Javascript NumberFormat
I am using the following method - NumberFormat() to format numbers for locale countries. Most of the numbers formatting is correct but for numbers from 1000 - 9999 it is not adding any spaces. Though for Poland it should actually insert a space for thousand separators.
Wiki - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator#Examples_of_use
Code -


const amount1 = 123.987;
const amount2 = 1234.987;
const amount3 = 12345.987;
const amount4 = 123456.987;
const numberFormat = new Intl.NumberFormat('pl-PL');

console.log(numberFormat.format(amount1));
console.log(numberFormat.format(amount2));
console.log(numberFormat.format(amount3));
console.log(numberFormat.format(amount4));



Output -
123,987
1234,987 // It should be 1 234,987
12 345,987
123 456,987

Let me know if there is any configuration I am missing or something in terms of understanding.

See this question, though the answers don't work for me on Firefox.

@Pointy : Thx for the pointer ..for me its working in Firefox 125 - https://jsfiddle.net/n2dmq98u/ and in Edge 122. Since my app users are mostly the latest Chrome(99% users) so I believe I can go with the solution ..though I believe this option is not going to change anything else ?
